# How to substring in java based on length?

Tags: java

I want to substring(starting chars) a string in java based on length.
for example if string1 is greater than 4000 bytes I want make that string into less than or equal to 4000 bytes string .(starting chars need to be trimmed not last chars)

Comment: Where is your codes ?

Comment: Try using [`String.length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) and [`String.substring(begin, end)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29). Then read a book about Java, because this is very basic string manipulation, so pretty much any book on Java would cover it.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
trimmed = str.substring(Math.max(0, str.length() - 4000));
```

(Bonus points if you can figure out what it is doing :-) )

However, note that this trims `str` to at most 4000 **characters**.  Trimming a Java string to a given number of bytes makes no sense unless you specify the character encoding.  And even if you do, it is a bit gnarly ... for variable length encodings such as UTF-8.

And it is worth noting that this can fail if your string contains Unicode codepoints outside of plane 0.

Comment: The second parameter is optional here (by default it substrings until the end).

Answer (score 0):

it is literally this

```
String s = sourceString.substring(/*Position to substring from*/ 0);
```

Comment: @Thilo didn't downvote, but it doesn't actually work. `String.substring(0)` just returns the string.

Comment: one can assume that the reader is able to fill in the clearly labelled `/*Position to substring from*/`. Maybe one assumes too much.

Comment: ouch man read the comment text it is literally that self explanatory